# Manage social login authentication data

Tags: php

I am building a `REST API` in `PHP` for social login(like Facebook,Gmail etc.). I want to know that how to design database structure for storing their credentials. Also If same email of user is registered in different social accounts then what should I have to do:
-- stop user to create another account with same email
-- create multiple account with same email
-- Or merge their account in one email
Please Guide me.Thanks

Comment: this platform is not a free source code provider, try google and do some effort, you should write some code and if you facing any error on code then upload on stackoverflow & we help to solve your error

Comment: merge their account in one... just store the useful information that you get from api of social media...

Answer (score 0):

According to me it's better to create a proper database structure for your project first. Then, whenever you access Google or facebook api there will be an access token provided to you.

Using that token you can retrieve details that you have requested permission for and store them automatically in the database. It's better to maintain a single account for all types of social authentication.

I guess there is no concept of multiple accounts using social authentication. There is no point in creating multiple accounts in social authentication.

OAuth is actually called open authentication. If you create multiple accounts for multiple social oauth providers there is no point in it actually.

Comment: Thanks @B001ᛦ for the edits. It appeared me to post a complete answer instead of just commenting it. Sorry if I am wrong